# Synology DSM shared folder deleted but still showing on network

Tags: folder-redirection, synology

I created a shared folder on DSM and used it for Folder Redirection with a Windows GPO.  Then I deleted the GPO and deleted the Shared Folder on the Synology.  It doesn't show up anywhere on the DSM, but I can still see the share through Windows Explorer and OSX Finder.  I can also see the data in the folder.  How do I delete the share?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  It was nothing to do with my Synology.  The problem was on the Windows client.  Followed the steps in this link to correct the problem.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942974